# Problema al cargar imagenes en react

Tags: reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]feliz navidad. Estoy intentando cargar unas imágenes, cuyo id viene de un archivo json para que la carga sea dinámica, la carpeta de las imágenes se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto y ese id viene con el nombre que se encuentra guarda la imagen en la carpeta. Cuando esto se renderiza en el navegador aparece de esta forma:

```
<img src="/assets/marvel-spider.jpg" alt="Spider Man" class="card-img">
```

```
  return (
    <div className="col">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="row no-gutters">
          <div className="col-4">
            <img src={`/assets/${id}.jpg`} alt={superhero} className="card-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema, pero creo que para que ``src={`/assets/${id}.jpg`}`` funcione, la carpeta ``assets`` deberia estar dentro de la carpeta ``public``.

Comment: Hola @AgustinG. me fuiste de mucha ayuda, el problema era que no se mostraban las imágenes, pero hice lo que me indicaste y listo. Mil gracias.!